# PineScript Place order when time is exactly 10:59:59

Tags: pine-script

I'm wondering how I can execute a order at a specific time each day (10:59:59) is where I want to place an order.
This is what I tried so far, but it repeats during the day and not only at (10:59:59)

```
targetYear      = input(0,  "Year (use 0 for all)",    minval = 0)
targetMonth     = input(0,  "Month (use 0 for all)",   minval = 0, maxval = 12)
targetDay       = input(0,  "Day (use 0 for all)",     minval = 0, maxval = 31)
targetHour      = input(10, "Hour (use 24 for all)",   minval = 0, maxval = 24)
targetMinute    = input(59, "Minute (use 60 for all)", minval = 0, maxval = 60)
targetSecond    = input(59, "Second (use 60 for all)", minval = 0, maxval = 60)

// Detect target date/time or greater, until the next higher generic value (i.e., using its default value in Inputs) changes.
targetReached =
  (targetYear   == 0  or year       >= targetYear)   and
  (targetMonth  == 0  or month      >= targetMonth)  and
  (targetDay    == 0  or dayofmonth >= targetDay)    and
  (targetHour   == 24 or hour       >= targetHour)   and
  (targetMinute == 60 or minute     >= targetMinute) and
  (targetSecond == 60 or second     >= targetSecond)

if targetReached[1] == false and targetReached == true
    if strategy.position_size == 0
        //Place order..
```

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: first of all `targetMinute == 60` and `targetSecond == 60` is meanless because it never reaches to this value after they are 59.secondly it returns true each hour greater than 10 until day ends.

Comment: That's correct. Main issue is that it returns true each hour, I'm looking to trigger only once at the specific hour, minute and second of the day - not sure how I manage this..

Comment: assume you're using 1h timeframe. just replace `(targetHour==24 or hour >= targetHour)` with `(hour <= targetHour+1 and hour >= targetHour)`